# How can I allocate a pointer clean way?

Tags: c

I am building a tree to find what path is the faster.
I read on the input stream the links between rooms.

For example I can have this type of map:

```
##start
0 1 0
##end
1 5 0
2 9 0
3 13 0
0-2
2-3
3-1
```

Start indicates the room where I start and end the room where I need to arrive.

I have a variable

```
 struct s_tree         **leaf;
```

which is an array of pointers to other rooms.
For example if I have:

```
0-2 and 0-3
```

`leaf[0]` will point to the room 2 and `leaf[1]` will point to the room 3.

At the moment I allocate it this way:

```
 root->leaf = xmalloc(sizeof(t_tree) * 100);
```

Problem is, I don't know how many bytes I need to allocate this variable.
If there are more than 100 links, I will have invalid writes.
I can allocate 100000 to be sure but it won't be very "clean".
I already tried to realloc it but it doesn't work; it's worse.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have to use `realloc()` and add links on demand.

Comment: Every time I need to ad another links I tried to do   tmp->leaf = realloc(tmp->leaf, 4);
 but it doesn't worked. I have a invalide next size error.

Comment: That's because you are giving it the wrong parameters. The second paramter needs to be the new size. Not the size to grow by.

Comment: 1. Don't overwrite the pointer directly, check first if `realloc()` did not return `NULL`, 2. Why size is 4?

Comment: @iharob As far as I can understand, Dimitri tries to build his tree in a dynamically allocated array. When he `realloc`s the array, *ALL* pointers will become invalid because they are pointing at the old array location.He would have to scan the array and relocate all pointers to keep the tree structure unchanged....

Comment: What do you mean by not overwriting the pointer directly ?

Comment: @CiaPan then what would be the point of `realloc()`.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov instead of `tmp->leaf = realloc(...)`, `void *temp = realloc(...); if (temp == NULL) dontContinue(); tmp->leaf = temp;`.

Comment: @CiaPan: Well, there's that thing about solving problems by adding another layer of indirection. I'd say it fits here.

Comment: @iharob it doesn't work, I have a segmentation fault at the beginning. What Ciapan said is right, when I will realloc my pointers all the pointers I had stored in my array would be lost no ? Sorry for my bad english it isn't my native language.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov You are losing the benefits of an array if you are storing pointers. Better to store array indices. If you don't want to do that and still want to use pointers then its better not to use arrays. Use a linked list where each node is dynamically allocated. That will automatically solve the problem of needing to know how much to allocate up front (you don't need to know as you just keep adding more linked list nodes). But of course that makes it difficult to just index into the node. Which brings us back to the array and `realloc`. Conclusion: store indices not pointers.

Comment: Or, if you have a reasonable assumption about the size of the tree, you can allocate larges pages (arrays) and chain them to a linked list. Asymptotically it's still bad, bud in practice will be orders of magnitude faster than a plain linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is, I don't know how many bytes I need to allocate this variable.

Using `realloc` is probably the best option.

> I already tried to realloc it but it doesn't work; it's worse.

It isn't clear what "it doesn't work" means. It would be a good idea to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can analyse and help you fix, or accurately describe what's going wrong.

You haven't done that, so I have to explain everything like you're doing everything wrong, in spite of however half-correct your understanding might be.

I'll cover crippling problems that people commonly face when using `realloc` first, and then move on to the other area of concern you seem to be emphasising in this question: Performance, and how you can improve it using `realloc`.

---

Firstly, `realloc` might return a new pointer. That pointer might be a null pointer, in which case `realloc` has failed and the old pointer is still valid. It's important to keep that old pointer around for a little while, so that if `realloc` returns `NULL` you haven't leaked your old memory region...

**NOTE: Attempting to dereference a null pointer is obviously a bad idea**. It's usually a good idea to use a pattern like this:

```
void *temp = realloc(array, new_size * sizeof *array);
if (temp == NuLL) {
    /* Handle allocation error...
     * It usually makes sense to let the user know and exit. */
    free(array); // NOTE: We can free the old array object; it hasn't leaked yet!
    perror("realloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
array = temp;
```

When `realloc` returns a new pointer, all of the old pointers in your tree will become invalid; they point to the old memory region, which has of course been reclaimed.

**Any attempt to use these dangling pointers (as they are commonly called) might result in erratic behaviour such as segfaults, strange logic bugs or behaviours otherwise described as "undefined"!** This undesirable consequence might not occur immediately; it might happen at some point in the future, incurring its cost as maintenance.

The simplest solution to this problem is to replace the pointer members of your nodes with `size_t` (unsigned integer) members, denoting the index at which the nodes reside rather than pointers to which the nodes reside.

More complex solutions might involve using a `union` of pointers and `size_t`, converting the pointers to `size_t` before `realloc`, and back to pointers after. This might be a consideration if the simpler, more naive approach is too slow.

---

At this point we've discussed both of the crippling problems that most commonly arise from using `realloc` in a similar fashion to your needs. As I said, though, it isn't clear that "it doesn't work" means "it crashes"; perhaps your problem is performance related.

Of course, `realloc` is unlikely to solve your performance woes if you're calling it every time you add an element to your collection. Compared to  `malloc`, such an algorithm would in fact be worse due to the overhead of copying between memory regions (when a block can't simply be resized).

You need to resize by a factor (e.g. double or triple the size of your array), and only when you need to, in order to see a benefit when using `realloc`. Then you'll start to see some benefit in the form of cache locality, for one.

Consider using some code like this as a helper function:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void *add_element(void **array, size_t *array_size, void const *element, size_t const element_size) {
    if (SIZE_MAX / element_size <= *array_size) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char (*temp)[element_size] = *array_size & (*array_size + 1)
                               ? *array
                               : realloc(*array, (*array_size * 2 + 1) * element_size);

    if (temp == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    *array = temp;
    temp += (*array_size)++;
    return element
         ? memcpy(temp, element, element_size)
         : memset(temp, 0,       element_size);
}
```

This example program, using a linked list instead of a tree, but solves a similar set of `realloc`-related problems:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int value;
    size_t next_index;
};

int main(void) {
    void *list = NULL;
    size_t list_size = 0;
    struct list *head = NULL;
    int x;
    srand(time(0));
    do {
        x = rand();
        head = add_element(&list,
                           &list_size,
                           &(struct list){ .value = x
                                         , .next_index = head
                                                       ? head - (struct list *) list
                                                       : SIZE_MAX },
                           sizeof (struct list));
    } while (x != 42);

    for (struct list *i = head; i != NULL; i = list->next_index != SIZE_MAX
                                             ? (struct list *) list + i->next_index
                                             : NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", i->value);
    }
}
```

---

At this point in time, more details regarding your algorithm are necessary to describe where to go from here. What I'm uncertain about is the format of the data that supposedly describes the path from room to room; it makes no sense to me.

What I am (almost) certain about is that you'll need *two* sets of variables corresponding to the `list` and `list_size` variables that I have; you'll most certainly want to use *four* variables: Perhaps `vertex` and `vertex_count` (where nodes/vertices are stored; the first of which is the `root` of your tree, perhaps?), `edge` and `edge_count` (or `leaf` and `leaf_count`, if you like).

---

With all of that said, I'm sure you can handle the rest... but feel free to update your question and ping me if you're still having problems :)